# Fetch request with Wordpress Rest api isn't working (Only on Edge)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, fetch, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to to get informations from a custom WordPress API endpoint using the GET method. For performing this, I have to use the cookies authentication system of WordPress.

I'm using JavaScript and the fetch API. It works perfectly well on Mozilla Firefox and  Google Chrome, but when I run my code in Edge, it return a 403 error.

My version of Edge is :
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

̶A̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶E̶d̶g̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶g̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶D̶e̶v̶T̶o̶o̶l̶ ̶p̶a̶n̶e̶l̶,̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶N̶e̶t̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶t̶a̶b̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶

Here is my code :

```
fetch(WP_API_Settings.root + 'my-custom-endpoint', {
    headers:{
            'X-WP-Nonce': WP_API_Settings.nonce,
    }
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((response) => {
     //My code
})
```

Comment: When using F12 developer tools, have you ever check whether it contains some JavaScript error, you could also add some debugger to verify whether this method is executed? Besides, you could also refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to catch the error and check the detailed error message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was finally able to get the error message. The error code is "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce". When I look to my request, the x-wp-nonce header exist, and it works well on other browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix the problem by adding the `credentials: 'same-origin'` parameter.

```
fetch(WP_API_Settings.root + 'my-custom-endpoint', {
    headers:{
        'X-WP-Nonce': WP_API_Settings.nonce,
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((response) => {
     //My code
})
```

Comment: I get 400 - Bad Request using that code?